# How to write the matrix in the required form?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I know how to write a block matrix. It's done like

```
\[
Q=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
{\{A\}}_{l\times l} & 0} \\
\hline
0} & B }
\end{array}
\right]
\]
```

But I want to add a row and column to my matrix .That is I want to write it like this:

> Row: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>   Column:
>   1
>   1
>   1
>   1
>   1
>   1
>   1
>   1
>   1

And then in the gap I want to add my block matrix.

I am adding an image for that how I want it. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: please show us (the code in form of small complete document, which we can compile)  what you try so far!

Answer (score 3):

One can simply use `array` and a small trick for getting a bigger letter for the blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Block}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\smash{$\mbox{\LARGE$#1$}_{#2}$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
Q=\left[
\begin{array}{@{}cccc|ccc@{}}
1      & 1 & \dots                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 1 & \dots       & 1 \\
1      &   &                      &                       &   &             &   \\
\vdots &   & \Block{A}{l\times l} &                       &   & \Block{0}{} &   \\
1      &   &                      &                       &   &             &   \\
\cline{2-7}
1      &   &                      &                       &   &             &   \\
\vdots &   & \Block{0}{}          &                       &   & \Block{B}{} &   \\
1      &   &                      &                       &   &             &
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent all your answers. +1 for all.

Answer (score 1):

You can always put an array inside another array, or use `\multicols` or `\multirows` (multirow package, goes back to text mode).  Now, expanding the cells to fit the space is more problematic.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\multirow{5}{*}{$\begin{array}{c|c}
 {A}_{l\times l} & 0 \\
 \hline
 0 & B
 \end{array}$}}\\
1 \\
1 \\
\vdots \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This solution aligns to the outer matrix.  It uses `\raisebox` instead of `\multirow` (shift distance is fudged).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\
1 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{A_{l\times l}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0} \\
1 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\
\cline{2-6}
\vdots & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\raisebox{-1ex}[0pt][0pt]{$0$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\raisebox{-1ex}[0pt][0pt]{$B$}} \\
1 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} 
\end{array}\right]$
\end{document}
```

[image: second demo]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using  `pstricks` for the vertical line and `\booktabs` for the horizontal line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow, blkarray, delarray}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\[ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \pnode{A} & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & & & \\
1 & & \mathclap{A} \\[-1ex]
\vdots & & & & & & \\[-1.5ex]
\vdots \\[-2.5ex]
 \cmidrule(r){2-7}
 \vdots \\[-1.5ex]
 \vdots & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\raisebox{1.5ex}{$ B $}}\\
1 & & & \phantom{1}\pnode{B}
\end{bmatrix} \]
\pcline[offset=\arraycolsep, linewidth=0.4pt]{-}(A)(B)
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]